# MySQL cardinality of NULL values

Tags: mysql, indexing

This is a recreation of a real table. Say I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`col` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `testTable` (col) VALUES (NULL), ('a'), (NULL), ('b'), (NULL), ('c'), (NULL), ('d'), (NULL), ('e'), (NULL), ('f');
ALTER TABLE `testTable` ADD INDEX (`col`);
OPTIMIZE TABLE `testTable`;
SHOW INDEX FROM `testTable`;
```

I get

```
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| testTable |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| testTable |          1 | col      |            1 | col         | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Why is the cardinality of `col` 12 and not 7? There are 7 unique values, so why are all the NULLs counted individually? Does this increase the size of the index? As soon as I use empty strings instead of NULL values, the cardinality goes down. Which is the preferred value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html)

> Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so the value is not necessarily exact even for small tables

This means that the NULL values arent stored as duplicates in the column which makes sense. NULL arent values that arent known. Hence no two NULLs are equal.

Refer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191504(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Edit: This is why you cant compare NULL values in SQL with `=` you always have to use `is NULL`

Conclusion: Cardinality 12 is correct.

Edit: I forgot to answer your other questions.

**Does this increase the size of the index?** The answer is in MySQL documentation

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

**As soon as I use empty strings instead of NULL values, the cardinality goes down. Which is the preferred value?** There is no *preferred* value as such. If empty string work for your purpose use them. Cardinality goes down because *empty string = empty string* is correct but *NULL = NULL* is not

Comment: "Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers" Does this mean even VARCHAR values won't be counted correctly?

Comment: No, that means that the statistics are stored as integers , not the data itself. So in corner cases like NULLs chances are that the statistics will mess up. I've also edited my answer to answer your additional questions.